# Writing a While loop with row/column variables?

Tags: vba, while-loop

I am very new to VBA and still trying to learn everything. I wrote this simple code to bring a prompt up for a cell missing input. I would like to apply this to other cells, i.e. Date, Shift and so on, but I am unsure of how to write the while loop. All the cells are in row 2.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
If Cells(2, 5).Value = "" Then
    MsgBox "Operator Name Required", vbInformation, "ALERT: Missing Information"
    Cancel = True
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: No need for a loop - you could just use an `If/ElseIf` to check them all - if any of them fail, it will prompt your user.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow.

You could use a `While loop`, sure, but the best approach here is to use a `For loop`

Let's say that your cells are in row 2, in the columns 5, 6, 7 and 8.
So, what you gotta do is:

```
For i = 5 To 8
    If Cells(2, i).Value = "" Then
        MsgBox "Operator Name Required", vbInformation, "ALERT: Missing Information"
        Cancel = True
    End If
Next
```

Let me explain what is going on here:

We created a variable `i` that is changing it's value from 5 to 8 each time the inner code repeats.
So we use that variable `i` to set our column index value, interating between each one of the desired columns.

Of course, the prompt will always show "Operator Name Required", and that probably isn't what you need.

In this case, you gotta create multiple `If-End If` statements, catching each one of the desired cells, like:

```
If Cells(2, 5).Value = "" Then
    MsgBox "Operator Name Required", vbInformation, "ALERT: Missing Information"
    Cancel = True
End If

If Cells(2, 6).Value = "" Then
    MsgBox "Operator Id Required", vbInformation, "ALERT: Missing Information"
    Cancel = True
End If

If Cells(2, 7).Value = "" Then
    MsgBox "Operator Date of Birth Required", vbInformation, "ALERT: Missing Information"
    Cancel = True
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a big fan of `while` loops, I'd rather know exactly for how long a loop will run, so my suggestion will be a slightly different loop.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)

    Dim firstCol As Long, lastCol As Long
    firstCol = 5
    lastCol = 10

    Dim C As Long   'Your variable to loop through columns

    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Set sht = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Your Sheet Name To Check")   'Without declaring and using this, if the user is _
                                                                    on a different sheet than the one intended for this macro, _
                                                                    the macro will fire up even if the user already completed

    For C = firstCol To lastCol
        If sht.Cells(2, C).Value = "" Then
            MsgBox "Operator " & sht.Cells(1, C).Value & " Required", vbInformation, "ALERT: Missing Information"
            Cancel = True
        End If
    Next C

End Sub
```

You can assign your **lastCol** variable more dynamically if you think in the future the number of columns will change, see this for further help on getting last row/column: https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/7/7/5-different-ways-to-find-the-last-row-or-last-column-using-vba

PS: @Lodi has already answered similarly, but was in the middle of writing this, so here are my 2 cents anyway.